# Не работает json_encode с большим массивом

Tags: php, json

Не работает json_encode с большим массивом...

```
$MySql = new mysqli($hm, $un, $pw, $db);

$query = "SELECT * FROM `units`";
$result = $MySql->query($query);

// print_r($result);

$data = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
// print_r($data);
echo json_encode($data);
```

Эту таблицу прекрасно выводит, в ней примерно 100 строк и 5 столбцов, а из таблицы `tb_country` ничего не выводится, хотя `print_r($data)` возвращает массив с данными.

```
$MySql = new mysqli($hm, $un, $pw, $db);

$query = "SELECT * FROM `tb_country`";
$result = $MySql->query($query);

// print_r($result);

$data = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
// print_r($data);
echo json_encode($data);
```

Ничего не возвращает...

Может ли это быть из-за большого массива? В этой таблице около 250 строк и 12 столбцов, и в них много данных...

Comment: Ошибку можно узнать выполнив `json_last_error` https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-last-error.php

Comment: Дапм $data можете предоставить? Кодировка utf8?

Comment: `$MySql->set_charset("utf8")`

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [Code] => ABW [Name] => Aruba [Continent] => North America [Region] => Caribbean [SurfaceArea] => 193.00 [IndepYear] => [Population] => 103000 [LifeExpectancy] => 78.4 [GNP] => 828.00 [GNPOld] => 793.00 [LocalName] => Aruba [GovernmentForm] => Nonmetropolitan Territory of The Netherlands [HeadOfState] => Beatrix [Capital] => 129 [Code2] => AW ) [1] => Array ( [Code] => AFG [Name] => Afghanistan [Continent] => Asia [Region] => Southern and Central Asia [SurfaceArea] => 652090.00... это то, что поместилось) (превышение допустимой длины на 85862 символа))